# Peut-on utiliser 'télétravailler' couramment ?

Tags: usage, néologismes, travail

J'entends plutôt 'faire du télétravail', 'être en télétravail' (leurs formes conjuguées). Peut-on utiliser le verbe 'télétravailler' ?

> Cette semaine, je télétravaille.

Comment: C'est un néologisme qui prendra probablement un peu de temps avant d'être admis par l'académie mais il ne me choque pas.

Comment: A noter que, de mon expérience, c'est surtout utilisé depuis le printemps/l'été 2020. Le télétravail a été boosté en région parisienne par les grèves RATP/SNCF de l'hiver 2019/2020 mais à ce moment, je n'ai jamais entendu "je télétravaille".

Comment: Plus généralement, [voir aussi](https://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/dictionnaires/vocabulaire-enseignement-distance-et-teletravail.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verbal forms are attested since at least the early eighties.

> Conclusion : lorsque la femme télétravaille à domicile, elle le fait dans la salle à manger...
>
> *Pénélope, pour l'histoire des femmes*, Collectif, 1982.

It wasn't mainstream for a while because WFH wasn't common at all except in niche sectors.

I believe I've been using the verb *télétravailler* since at least 15 years because that was already an option in the companies I worked for.

Because of the pandemic, the verb is now ubiquitous in government and corporate communication, [e.g.](https://travail-emploi.gouv.fr/droit-du-travail/la-vie-du-contrat-de-travail/article/teletravail-mode-d-emploi):

> **L’employeur peut-il refuser que je télétravaille ?**
>
> - Oui, mais il doit motiver sa réponse.